# mysql - insert/update string values without wrapping quotes

Tags: mysql, loops, cursor, quotes, declare

I have created a routine that loops through a table and concatenates the results in a variable. That variable is later used with PREPARE and EXECUTE to insert a bunch of rows in one go.

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE fetched_name VARCHAR(32);

    DECLARE loop_finished TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE loop_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM first_example_table;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET loop_finished = 1;

    SET @insert_entry = NULL;

        OPEN loop_cursor;

            looping: LOOP

                FETCH loop_cursor INTO fetched_name;
    
                    IF
                    loop_finished = 1
                    THEN
    
                        LEAVE looping;
    
                    END IF;
    
                SET @insert_list = CONCAT_WS("), (", @insert_list, fetched_name);

            END LOOP;

        CLOSE loop_cursor;

    SET @insert_list = CONCAT("INSERT INTO second_example_temple (name) VALUES (", @insert_list, ")");

    PREPARE insert_query FROM @insert_list;
    EXECUTE insert_query;

END
```

So far, that actually would work as intended. The problem is, however, that the prepared query contains the value without quotes, as shown here:

```
INSERT INTO second_example_temple (name) VALUES (Bill), (Peter), (Tom);
```

MySQL refuses that query for the missing quotes, it expects the query to look like this:

```
INSERT INTO second_example_temple (name) VALUES ("Bill"), ("Peter"), ("Tom");
```

Is there any good workaround for that problem? Ideally **without** setting the quotes manually and **without** using CONCAT or CONCAT_WS, as that would become very complicated when setting more fields beside the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QUOTE like in the example.

MySQL doesn't mind quotes even for Numbers, but NULL have to be entered without quotes

> ```
> CREATE TABLE employees (email varchar(19))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO employees VALUES ('test@test.de'),('test2@test.de'),('test1@test.de')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE createEmailList (
>   INOUT emailList varchar(4000)
> )
> BEGIN
>   DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
>   DECLARE emailAddress varchar(100) DEFAULT "";
>
>   -- declare cursor for employee email
>   DEClARE curEmail 
>       CURSOR FOR 
>           SELECT email FROM employees;
>
>   -- declare NOT FOUND handler
>   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
>         FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
> SET emailList = '';
>   OPEN curEmail;
>
>   getEmail: LOOP
>       FETCH curEmail INTO emailAddress;
>       SET @a = emailAddress;
>       IF finished = 1 THEN 
>           LEAVE getEmail;
>       END IF;
>       -- build email list
>       SET emailList = CONCAT(QUOTE(emailAddress),";",emailList);
>       SET @b = CONCAT(QUOTE(emailAddress),';',emailList);
>   END LOOP getEmail;
>   CLOSE curEmail;
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL createEmailList(@emaillist)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @emaillist
> ```
>
> ```
> | @emaillist                                      |
> | :---------------------------------------------- |
> | 'test1@test.de';'test2@test.de';'test@test.de'; |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=337b94c77a6d7ed79ee0608805a00bf4)*